# Keras training cats vs dogs gives constant validation accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am following [this keras tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) to train a cats/dogs model with few data. I ran the exact code as given on the [github](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d), but the accuracy stays 0.5 and never changes.

My keras version is 2.0.9.

```
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 800 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/50
125/125 [==============================] - 150s 1s/step - loss: 0.7777 - acc: 0.4975 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/50
125/125 [==============================] - 158s 1s/step - loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/50
125/125 [==============================] - 184s 1s/step - loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 4/50
125/125 [==============================] - 203s 2s/step - loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.4940 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 5/50
  3/125 [..............................] - ETA: 2:30 - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.5417
```

Does anyone know what's the reason behind this?

My `data` directory looks like this:

```
data/
    train/
        cats/
            cat846.jpg
            cat828.jpg
            cat926.jpg
            cat382.jpg
            cat792.jpg
            ...
        dogs/
            dog533.jpg
            dog850.jpg
            dog994.jpg
            dog626.jpg
            dog974.jpg
            ...
    validation/
        cats/
            cat1172.jpg
            cat1396.jpg
            cat1336.jpg
            cat1347.jpg
            cat1211.jpg
            ...
        dogs/
            dog1014.jpg
            dog1211.jpg
            dog1088.jpg
            dog1207.jpg
            dog1186.jpg
            ...
```

***It seems to have something to do with OS. The above result was on Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine. I copied the code to windows, it worked correctly. But why?***

Comment: Can you post your networks code? Also, what is the output shape? 2 column or one column? I feel as though this is a sigmoid softmax problem

Comment: @djk47463 The code is on the [github link](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d) and I changed nothing.

Comment: Did you experienced the same validation when trying to run this different times? Are you positive that there were no differences in the Linux and Windows setups? Perhaps you changed some parameter, or your folder setup is not adequate.